# Adding Custom Field To Shortcode Display In WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields, shortcode

I have searched high and low on this site as well as many others and have been unable to find an answer to my question.

How can I add a custom field to the [product_category] shortcode display in WooCommerce?

Example: I would like to display 2 prices:
1. The full and actual price that is already displayed.
2. The cost per month price. Which is just a custom field where I manually enter in $XX.XX.

Any and all help is appreciated. Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember, shortcodes are just a convenient wrapper for using other existing functions. If you look inside of `class-wc-shortcodes.php` you'll find that the `[product_category]` shortcode includes the `content-product.php` template to output the products. [You can override any template in WooCommerce by copying it to your theme folder](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/): create a new folder called `woocommerce` inside your theme folder, and copy `content-product.php` into it. You can then amend this template so that it outputs your custom field.

Comment: Thank you for the input, this helped me immensely. I spent way too much time on such a simple fix lol. I can't upvote you yet, but when I get enough rep I will!